# How do I add boundaries to walls?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game similar to the Binding Of Isaac. I want to have rocks around the screen that block the player's movement.

Where the rock layout is made:

```
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ", 
"                                                                ",
"              jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj                   ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                ",
"                                                                "
]
rockxcoord = 0
rockycoord = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "j":
            rock = rocks(rockxcoord, rockycoord)
            rockGroup.add(rock)
        rockxcoord +=32
    rockycoord += 50
    rockxcoord = 0
```

Where the boundaries are set

```
    for rock in rockGroup:
        screen.blit(rock.image, [rock.rect.x, rock.rect.y])
        rockCollisionList = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(playerOne, rockGroup, False)
        for rock in rockCollisionList:
            if playerOne.rect.x < rock.rect.x:
                playerOne.rect.x = rock.rect.x - 90
            if playerOne.rect.x > rock.rect.x:
                playerOne.rect.x = rock.rect.x + 80
```

I have successfully added boundaries on the x axis. However, when doing the same with the y axis it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [PyGame's Sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  There's a [good tutorial](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html) on them too.
It's a little bit more work initially, but it will save time later.  Really, take the time to learn it.  It's worth the investment.

Your walls can just be something simple:

```
class WallSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A stationay sprite"""
    def __init__( self, position, image ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image        = image
        self.rect         = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = position 

    def udpate( self ):
        # does not move
        pass
```

Create a bunch of walls.  Obviously it's more efficient to make a 10 by 1 unit wall as a single sprite, but for the sake of example we will make walls Lego™ style.

```
# Create 20 randomly-placed walls
wall_image = pygame.image.load("brick_32.png").convert_alpha()
wall_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()   # a group for all the wall sprites
for i in range(20):
    # create a wall at a random position
    new_wall = WallSprite( ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) ), wall_image )
    wall_sprites.add( new_wall )  # put into the sprite group
```

[image: brick_32.png]  `brick_32.png`

In your main loop, the sprite groups can be used for both painting the sprites, and the group collide function to see if your player has hit *any* wall.

```
# Main loop
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        # handle direction keys ...

    # move / update the player sprite
    player_sprite.update()

    # handle player <-> wall sprite collisions (for *ALL* walls)
    if ( len( pygame.sprite.spritecollide( player_sprite, wall_sprites, False ) ) > 0 ):
        player_sprite.stop_moving()

    # re-paint the window
    screen.fill( GREEN )
    wall_sprites.draw()   # paints the entire sprite group
    player_sprite.draw()  # paint the player
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I've already been using pygame sprites. My problem is I dont know what to write to make it so that it stops moving when it touches the wall, but that it can still move to get away from the wall.

Comment: @Hadex02 - Say your player moves 5 pixels left.  At this makes it collide the wall, and also overlap by some amount.  The code has to detect that there would be a collision and then adjust the players movement.  Perhaps the wall was only 3 pixels away, the player can really only move 2 pixels before stopping.  So check for collisions before finalising the movement, and adjust for how far the player actually moved so it stops *against* the wall rather than overlapping.